# Issues with single-requests in Restangular

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I'm having a slight issue with my ability to consume REST data retrieved via Restangular in an angular controller. I have the following code which works fine for a list of accounts:

```
var baseAccounts = Restangular.all('accounts');

baseAccounts.getList().then(function(accounts) {
  $scope.accounts = accounts;
});
```

This works perfectly for a list. I use similar syntax for a single account:

```
var baseAccount = Restangular.one('accounts');

baseAccount.getList(GUID).then(function(returnedAccount) {
  $scope.currentAccount = returnedAccount;
});
```

I am using ng-repeat as the handling directive for my first request. I am attempting to bind with {{ account.name }} tags for the single request, but it does not seem to display any data despite the request being made properly. GUID is the parameter I must pass in to retrieve the relevant record.

I have combed through Restangular docs and it seems to me like I am composing my request properly. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**: I've tried all of the solutions listed here to no avail. It would seem Restangular is submitting the correctly structured request, but when it returns it through my controller it shows up as just a request for a list of accounts. When the response is logged, it shows the same response as would be expected for a list of accounts. I do not believe this is a scoping issue as I have encapsulated my request in a way that should work to mitigate that. So, there seems to be a disconnect between Request -> Restangular object/promise that populates the request -> data-binding to the request. Restangular alternates between returning the array of accounts or undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at:

https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#using-values-directly-in-templates

Since Angular 1.2, Promise unwrapping in templates has been disabled by default and will be deprecated soon.

Try:

```
$scope.accounts = baseAccounts.getList().$object;
```

Comment: I actually ended up removing restangular from my project because it wasn't as accessible and efficient as I had hoped. If this is the correct answer and someone else can verify, I'll mark it as answered. I would test, but I no longer have access to the project in this state. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @mattchue out of curiosity did you end up rolling your own implementation or move to another library?  I'm currently evaluating restangular and wondering if I'll have long term issues, etc.

Comment: I ran with my own implementation. Angular does a pretty good job of scoping, so check out angular's services if you're not already familiar and you can put together your own data stack fairly easily :)

Comment: Ok great thanks for the info.  I assume you ran with $resource and built conveniences around it?  Or did you go the bare metal approach and build up from $http?

Comment: bare metal all the way. I figured if I had to make my own REST implementation I wanted complete control so that it's tailored against my backend. I actually tried $resource before Restangular and was fairly confused by the docs. it doesn't seem like mgonto's upkeep of restangular has gone on the backburner, he hasnt authored a commit himself on that repo in over a year

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
var baseAccount = Restangular.one('accounts', GUID);

baseAccount.get().then(function(returnedAccount) {
  $scope.currentAccount = returnedAccount;
});
```

The problem here is that it's expecting an array to be returned. I'm assuming that you are expecting an account object. Thus we need to use the get function, intead of getList()

Comment: I've tried all of the solutions listed here to no avail. It would seem Restangular is submitting the correctly structured request, but when it returns it through my controller it shows up as just a request for a list of accounts. When the response is logged, it shows the same response as would be expected for a list of accounts. I do not believe this is a scoping issue as I have encapsulated my request in a way that should work to mitigate that. So, there seems to be a disconnect between Request -> Restangular object/promise that populates the request -> data-binding to the request.

Answer (score 0):

The one() function has a second argument that accepts an id e.g. .one('users', 1). You can take a use of it.

**CODE**

```
var baseAccount = Restangular.one('accounts', 1); //1 would be account id

baseAccount.getList('account').then(function(returnedAccount) {
  $scope.currentAccount = returnedAccount;
});
```

**OR**

```
var baseAccount = Restangular.one('accounts', 1); //1 would be account id

baseAccount.all('account').getList().then(function(returnedAccount) {
  $scope.currentAccount = returnedAccount;
});
```

For more info take look at [**github issue**](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular/issues/450)

Hope this could help you, Thanks.

Comment: @mattchue does it helpful to?

Comment: It did, but I am still having my issue. I have updated the OP with more information. Thank you for your help!